# Black screen after trying to fix password

Tags: 12.04, boot, password

I went to fix the password and the entire screen took me to a BIOS type of black screen. When I'm stuck there it asks for a password, but it will not allow me to type anything. I tried pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> but nothing happened. I'm still stuck with the same black screen.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add more information about the steps you've followed and about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have been able to enter an account name or userid and it is now asking for a password.

When a password is entered, nothing happens on the screen, so try entering the password you will have set up carefully and hit  and see what happens.